# Add a MIME type on Windows 7 - IE

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer, mime-types

IE11 does not recognise the correct mime type of a file if the mime type is not made known to windows (at least I think that's what's going on). The drag & drop events of the browser show an empty mime type isntead of "text/csv". I know I can associate a mime type to CSV by installing something like Excel. I don't feel like installing Excel just to get something going there. Is there any other way to associate .CSV to **"text/csv"**?

Background: I'm a developer and I'm writing a drag & drop thing for a web application. I develop in *nixy systems but I have to support Windows so I have a barebones VM set up for testing. My customers will have Excel installed which gives CSV a mime type of "application/excel" or something along those lines.

Comment: well, note that the server sends the mime type, so if its coming in as "application/excel" then the server application needs to correctly specify "text/csv". as for setting the application association, see here for info on how windows/IE handle mime type config: http://www.ehow.com/how_6924444_edit-mime-types-ie.html

Comment: You misunderstand, apologies for not making this more clear: A user will pick up a file from his or her desktop and drag it onto the browser. There's no server involvement. The `ehow` method only works if you have a program that handles CSV naturally (like Excel), which I'm trying to avoid. Notepad is not good enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added `.csv` to the registry. CSV is now recognised as `text/csv`.

[image]